# How to fetch rows from a table based on a field which is present in a different table having a foreign key relationship with it?

Tags: python, sql, django, django-viewsets

I have two tables as follows in Django:

```
Table1: 
    - id
    - name
    - address
    - state
    - short_code
    
Table2: 
    - id
    - table1_id
    - p1, property (searchable field)
```

Relationship between Table1 and Table2: `Table1(1) -> Table2(n) [ 1->n ]`

Let's say I have a searchable property **p1** in **Table2**. How to fetch all the rows from **Table1** which is satisfying the following query parameters?

```
short_code(table1 field), state(table1 field), and property as p1(table2 field)
```

Remember, Table1 has 1:n relationship with Table2, so Table2 can have multiple rows satisfying foreign key relationship of field *id* from Table1.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do related lookups:

```
class MyModel1(models.Model):
   model2 = models.ForeignKey('myapp.MyModel2', related_name='model1',...)

class MyModel2(models.Model):
   fields...
```

Now you can do:

```
MyModel1.objects.filter(model2__pk=YOUR_MODEL2_PK)
```

Or

```
MyModel2.objects.filter(model1__pk=YOUR_MODEL_1_PK)
```

You can limit the results returned with `.only()`

> Note:
>
> Have a look at [the docs for many to one relationships](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/topics/db/examples/many_to_one/)
>
> Or [the docs for querysets](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/ref/models/querysets/#only)

Comment: This will take an inner join in both the tables and search the fields accordingly right?